# "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified" when everything is set up properly in tnsnames.ora

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to set up an Oracle test instance with [the Chinook database.](https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database)  So far, I've managed to:

- install Oracle server
- connect to the server with SQL Developer
- create a Chinook PDB
- run the setup script
- add Chinook to tnsnames.ora
- verify that it's in there correctly with `tnsping chinook`

But when I try to connect to it with application code, I get the infamous ORA-12154 error.  As near as I can tell from research online, that should not be happening if the tnsnames entry exists and is valid.

Using Data Provider for .NET, and following [Oracle's guidelines](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT163), I've set up my connection string as:

```
Data Source=chinook;User Id=chinook;Password=[my password]
```

The application code is running on the same computer as the Oracle server.

This feels like everything should be working... but it's not.  What else do I need to check for?

Comment: Is your application environment set up correctly for .NET to locate the tnsnames.ora file? Does the user executing the .NET connection have read privileges on the file?

Comment: @pmdba Can you elaborate on this?  I wasn't aware that that was a factor.

Comment: Generally this error is the result of tnsnames.ora not being found, or of a security/permissions issue reading the file. Your environment may be configured correctly for you to find the file when executing SQL*Plus or tnsping from the command line, but the application's execution context may be missing something. Common things to check are environment variables like ORACLE_HOME, TNS_ADMIN, or PATH.

Comment: @pmdba Thanks.  I had the other two set, but not ORACLE_HOME.  After setting that... no change.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924